# How to show DSL (query) processing in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, monitor, processlist

I want to know if there is something like "show processlist (mysql)" in ElasticSearch which shows the query processing.

Also if there is a way to stop a bad query processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now i found ES 2.3 has support this feature. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html

Answer (score 2):

You can run an API call to get information about the current tasks:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#_current_tasks_information

Example:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_tasks?pretty'
```

Damien